# Calculate limit or prove it does not exist

Tags: limits, trigonometry

$$  \lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{\cos(\frac{x}{2})}{\pi^2-x^2}  $$

I thought to change $x$ with $t$ like this:

$$  \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\cos(\frac{t+\pi}{2})}{\pi^2-(t+\pi)^2}  $$

Now I'm not sure how to continue..
Also I'm not allowed to use l'hopital rule or derivative at all.
Thank you

Comment: yes. sorry. fixing it..

Comment: Duplicate: [$\displaystyle\lim _{x\to \pi }(\frac{cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\pi ^2-x^2})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1066330/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%20%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%20%5Cpi%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Ccos(%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B2%7D)%7D%7B%5Cpi%5E2-x%5E2%7D%20%24&p=1)*)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Change variable $x=\pi-y$ $$A=\frac{\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\pi ^2-x^2}=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)}{2 \pi  y-y^2}$$ Now $y=2z$ $$A=\frac 14\frac{\sin (z)}{\pi  z- z^2}=\frac 1 {4\pi}\frac{\sin(z)}z \frac 1 {1-\frac z \pi}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $cos(\frac {\pi}{2})$ is exactly zero, the limit converges to zero. This is very easy to prove by definition, have a go at it yourself.

Comment: There was a mistake, its X and not PI at the numerator

Answer (score 0):

Write the given function as $$\frac{\sin
{x} }{2\cdot\sin\frac{x} {2}\cdot(\pi-x) \cdot(\pi+x)} $$ using $\sin2x=2\sin{x} \cos{x}$. Write $\sin{x} = \sin(\pi-x)$. Then $\sin(\pi-x)$ and $(\pi-x)$ cancel out.
The expression now is $$\lim_{x\to \pi} \frac{1}{2\cdot\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cdot(\pi+x)}$$ which yields the answer **$\frac{1}{4\pi}$**.